# AWS IOT Error: premature close at onclosenexttick

Tags: javascript, amazon-web-services, iot, aws-iot, aws-sdk-ios

**I am trying to build a basic AWS IOT Javascript application, below is the source code**

```
var awsIot = require('aws-iot-device-sdk');

var device = awsIot.device({
keyPath: 'xxx-private.pem.key',
certPath: 'xxx-certificate.pem.crt',
caPath: 'AmazonRootCA1.pem',
clientId: 'xxx_policy',
host: 'xxxxx.amazonaws.com'
});

device.on('connect', function() {
console.log('connect');
//device.subscribe('topic_1');
device.publish('MyConnectPolicy', JSON.stringify({ test_data: 'NodeJS server connected...'}));
});

device.on('message', function(topic, payload) {
console.log('message', topic, payload.toString());
});
```

On running this project I am getting below error

```
events.js:200
throw er; // Unhandled 'error' event
^
Error: premature close
at onclosenexttick (xxx/node_modules/end-of-stream/index.js:54:86)
at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:76:11)

Emitted 'error' event on DeviceClient instance at:
at MqttClient. (xxx/node_modules/aws-iot-device-sdk/device/index.js:772:15)
at MqttClient.emit (events.js:228:7)
at TLSSocket.f (xxx/node_modules/once/once.js:25:25)
at onclosenexttick (xxx/node_modules/end-of-stream/index.js:54:73)
at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:76:11)
```

Can someone address this, thanks in advance.

Comment: when I use openssl to check the connection it works fine,
**openssl s_client -connect xxxxEP:8883 -CAfile xxxAmazonRootCA1.pem -cert xxx.pem.crt -key xxx-private.pem.key
CONNECTED(00000003)**

Answer (score 1):

I recently had this same issue when trying to connect to a `thing` on AWS using the AWS-IoT-SDK for node. I finally found my solution on this [Github issue][https://github.com/aws/aws-iot-device-sdk-js/issues/304#issuecomment-608500683].

I didn't attach a policy to my `thing`.

To create a new policy for your `thing` you could do it while creating the thing or

```
In the left navigation pane, choose Secure, and then choose Policies. On the You don't have a policy yet page, choose Create a policy.

On the Create a policy page, in the Name field, enter a name for the policy (for example, MyIotPolicy). Do not use personally identifiable information in your policy names.
```

[Further reading](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/iot/latest/developerguide/create-iot-policy.html)

Comment: It'd be great if you added the required steps to your answer directly.